# How to get no text and no shadow below my app icon?

Tags: android, icons, homescreen

I've seen several apps that show no text below the icon in the home screen, and i want that for my app.
By searching here, I managed to prevent the app name to appear below the icon with the manifest, but I still get a small grey empty oval. 
Does anyone knows how to remove it also?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should always include a label under the icon. I can't think of **ANY** reason why you wouldn't.

Comment: I can think of a very important one: aesthetics. Several apps already don't include the shadow by this reason (e.g., Google traffic widget itself), some don't even include the name (SSH/SFTP Server, Ministocks, etc). Actually, I even think it should be an option for the user to remove the names of ALL app icons, i.e., an icon-only theme. This is what I've always used in all my Linux boxes since ages. It's fine to have the names when you're new to the OS, but once you have had your device for a month or two names are completely useless, and ugly.